What is the hard and fast rule for GMP mpf precision to number of significant digits
GMP currently works out of the box with a precision of 64 precision bits (I think that's what mp_bitcnt_t is called).
For me this works up to numbers of value up to around 1x10e-22 I think (where I'm using numbers 1.123... so 1 significant digit to the left of the decimal and 22 significant digits to the right). If I try to add more digits after that to like 1x10e-23 then things start going sideways. So of course I up the precision bits to something arbitrary like 128 which works.
But I was wondering if there was a less arbitrary way to figure out a more precise value to place there instead of just doubling it to 128 because I don't know what else to put in there.
I think I am basically asking what is the relationship of mp_bitcnt_t to significant decimal digits?

Simple rule of thumb is 1024 ~ 1k = 2^10 = 10^3

By experiment it seems that GMP works in 64 precision bit increments. The first 64 gives you about 22 decimal digits of precision. What's interesting is that you cannot get below 64 bits of precision initially. (which I was hoping to be able to use to cut down cpu-time).
GMP jumps up in 64 bit increments. So even if you set 58 it'll still set it at 64.
So every 64 precision bit chunk will give you about 18-20 decimal digit.
Code I've used to determine that below (in C (Swift) and awk):
void check_digits_to_gmp_prec(void)
{
    //pi to 2,000 digits
    char *pi = "3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510582097494459230781640628620899862803482534211706798214808651328230664709384460955058223172535940812848111745028410270193852110555964462294895493038196442881097566593344612847564823378678316527120190914564856692346034861045432664821339360726024914127372458700660631558817488152092096282925409171536436789259036001133053054882046652138414695194151160943305727036575959195309218611738193261179310511854807446237996274956735188575272489122793818301194912983367336244065664308602139494639522473719070217986094370277053921717629317675238467481846766940513200056812714526356082778577134275778960917363717872146844090122495343014654958537105079227968925892354201995611212902196086403441815981362977477130996051870721134999999837297804995105973173281609631859502445945534690830264252230825334468503526193118817101000313783875288658753320838142061717766914730359825349042875546873115956286388235378759375195778185778053217122680661300192787661119590921642019893809525720106548586327886593615338182796823030195203530185296899577362259941389124972177528347913151557485724245415069595082953311686172785588907509838175463746493931925506040092770167113900984882401285836160356370766010471018194295559619894676783744944825537977472684710404753464620804668425906949129331367702898915210475216205696602405803815019351125338243003558764024749647326391419927260426992279678235478163600934172164121992458631503028618297455570674983850549458858692699569092721079750930295532116534498720275596023648066549911988183479775356636980742654252786255181841757467289097777279380008164706001614524919217321721477235014144197356854816136115735255213347574184946843852332390739414333454776241686251898356948556209921922218427255025425688767179049460165346680498862723279178608578438382796797668145410095388378636095068006422512520511739298489608412848862694560424196528502221066118630674427862203919494504712371378696095636437191728746776465757396241389086583264599581339047802759009946576407895126946839835259570";
    
    for (int i = 32; i < 4096; i++)
    {
        mpf_t val;
        mpf_set_default_prec(i);
        mpf_init(val);
        mpf_set_str(val, pi, 10);
        gmp_printf("bits: %ld precision: %ld pi-digits: %.Ff\n", i, mpf_get_default_prec(), val);
        mpf_clear(val);
    }
    /*
     % cat outp | awk '{if (length(PREV) != length($6)) {print $1,$2,":",$2-PREV_F2,"-",$3,$4,":",$4-PREV_F4,"-",$5, length($6),":",length($6)-PREV_LEN; PREV_F2 = $2; PREV_F4 = $4};PREV_LEN=length($6);PREV = $6;}'
     bits: 32 : 32 - precision: 64 : 64 - pi-digits: 22 : 22
     bits: 65 : 33 - precision: 128 : 64 - pi-digits: 41 : 19
     bits: 129 : 64 - precision: 192 : 64 - pi-digits: 60 : 19
     bits: 193 : 64 - precision: 256 : 64 - pi-digits: 80 : 20
     bits: 257 : 64 - precision: 320 : 64 - pi-digits: 99 : 19
     bits: 321 : 64 - precision: 384 : 64 - pi-digits: 118 : 19
     bits: 385 : 64 - precision: 448 : 64 - pi-digits: 137 : 19
     bits: 449 : 64 - precision: 512 : 64 - pi-digits: 157 : 20
     bits: 513 : 64 - precision: 576 : 64 - pi-digits: 176 : 19
     bits: 577 : 64 - precision: 640 : 64 - pi-digits: 195 : 19
     bits: 641 : 64 - precision: 704 : 64 - pi-digits: 214 : 19
     bits: 705 : 64 - precision: 768 : 64 - pi-digits: 234 : 20
     bits: 769 : 64 - precision: 832 : 64 - pi-digits: 253 : 19
     bits: 833 : 64 - precision: 896 : 64 - pi-digits: 271 : 18
     bits: 897 : 64 - precision: 960 : 64 - pi-digits: 291 : 20
     bits: 961 : 64 - precision: 1024 : 64 - pi-digits: 311 : 20
     bits: 1025 : 64 - precision: 1088 : 64 - pi-digits: 330 : 19
     bits: 1089 : 64 - precision: 1152 : 64 - pi-digits: 349 : 19
     bits: 1153 : 64 - precision: 1216 : 64 - pi-digits: 369 : 20
     bits: 1217 : 64 - precision: 1280 : 64 - pi-digits: 388 : 19
     bits: 1281 : 64 - precision: 1344 : 64 - pi-digits: 407 : 19
     bits: 1345 : 64 - precision: 1408 : 64 - pi-digits: 426 : 19
     bits: 1409 : 64 - precision: 1472 : 64 - pi-digits: 446 : 20
     bits: 1473 : 64 - precision: 1536 : 64 - pi-digits: 465 : 19
     bits: 1537 : 64 - precision: 1600 : 64 - pi-digits: 484 : 19
     bits: 1601 : 64 - precision: 1664 : 64 - pi-digits: 502 : 18
     bits: 1665 : 64 - precision: 1728 : 64 - pi-digits: 523 : 21
     bits: 1729 : 64 - precision: 1792 : 64 - pi-digits: 542 : 19
     bits: 1793 : 64 - precision: 1856 : 64 - pi-digits: 561 : 19
     bits: 1857 : 64 - precision: 1920 : 64 - pi-digits: 580 : 19
     bits: 1921 : 64 - precision: 1984 : 64 - pi-digits: 600 : 20
     bits: 1985 : 64 - precision: 2048 : 64 - pi-digits: 619 : 19
     bits: 2049 : 64 - precision: 2112 : 64 - pi-digits: 637 : 18
     bits: 2113 : 64 - precision: 2176 : 64 - pi-digits: 658 : 21
     bits: 2177 : 64 - precision: 2240 : 64 - pi-digits: 676 : 18
     bits: 2241 : 64 - precision: 2304 : 64 - pi-digits: 696 : 20
     bits: 2305 : 64 - precision: 2368 : 64 - pi-digits: 715 : 19
     bits: 2369 : 64 - precision: 2432 : 64 - pi-digits: 735 : 20
     bits: 2433 : 64 - precision: 2496 : 64 - pi-digits: 754 : 19
     bits: 2497 : 64 - precision: 2560 : 64 - pi-digits: 773 : 19
     bits: 2561 : 64 - precision: 2624 : 64 - pi-digits: 792 : 19
     bits: 2625 : 64 - precision: 2688 : 64 - pi-digits: 812 : 20
     bits: 2689 : 64 - precision: 2752 : 64 - pi-digits: 831 : 19
     bits: 2753 : 64 - precision: 2816 : 64 - pi-digits: 850 : 19
     bits: 2817 : 64 - precision: 2880 : 64 - pi-digits: 869 : 19
     bits: 2881 : 64 - precision: 2944 : 64 - pi-digits: 889 : 20
     bits: 2945 : 64 - precision: 3008 : 64 - pi-digits: 908 : 19
     bits: 3009 : 64 - precision: 3072 : 64 - pi-digits: 927 : 19
     bits: 3073 : 64 - precision: 3136 : 64 - pi-digits: 947 : 20
     bits: 3137 : 64 - precision: 3200 : 64 - pi-digits: 966 : 19
     bits: 3201 : 64 - precision: 3264 : 64 - pi-digits: 985 : 19
     bits: 3265 : 64 - precision: 3328 : 64 - pi-digits: 1004 : 19
     bits: 3329 : 64 - precision: 3392 : 64 - pi-digits: 1024 : 20
     bits: 3393 : 64 - precision: 3456 : 64 - pi-digits: 1043 : 19
     bits: 3457 : 64 - precision: 3520 : 64 - pi-digits: 1061 : 18
     bits: 3521 : 64 - precision: 3584 : 64 - pi-digits: 1081 : 20
     bits: 3585 : 64 - precision: 3648 : 64 - pi-digits: 1101 : 20
     bits: 3649 : 64 - precision: 3712 : 64 - pi-digits: 1119 : 18
     bits: 3713 : 64 - precision: 3776 : 64 - pi-digits: 1139 : 20
     bits: 3777 : 64 - precision: 3840 : 64 - pi-digits: 1158 : 19
     bits: 3841 : 64 - precision: 3904 : 64 - pi-digits: 1178 : 20
     bits: 3905 : 64 - precision: 3968 : 64 - pi-digits: 1197 : 19
     bits: 3969 : 64 - precision: 4032 : 64 - pi-digits: 1216 : 19
     bits: 4033 : 64 - precision: 4096 : 64 - pi-digits: 1236 : 20
     %

     */
}


GMP works internally in terms of what it calls "limbs".  A "limb" is 64 digits.  (Like having 64 fingers on each hand. :-) )
